# Study of a parametric curve

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, graphing-functions, plane-curves, plane-geometry

geniuses.

We want to study this parametric curve in the neighborhood of zero :
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
x(t) &=& t - t^3 + 2t^4\\
y(t) &=& -2t + 2t^3 + t^5 \\
\end{array}
\right.
\
$$

We want to extract as much information as possible from this parameters. For example, what kind of point is it? Inflection point ? And the curve relative position to the tangent.

We want to extract these information using the Taylor Expansion/Serie formulas.

Thank you for your help and explanation, stackExchange explanations are really powerful to understand mathematics a bit better.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Taylor expansion doesn't make much sense when $x,y$ are polynomials in $t$.

Comment: Compute roots of $x,y$ and look for roots of $x$ *and* $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming and nice editing ! I hope this will make sense to someone here, cause it's the condition i've been given...

Comment: I am a bit confused? This is not a plane, it is [a curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7Bt+-+t%5E3+%2B+2+t%5E4%2C+-2+t+%2B+2+t%5E3+%2B+t%5E5%7D%2C+%7Bt%2C+-1%2C+1%7D%5D), right?

Comment: It's a curve indeed, sorry i just edited. (English is not my native language...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Taylor expansion is already done :-) You can write it
$$\begin{pmatrix}x(t) \\ y(t)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2\end{pmatrix}t + \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}t^2 + \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}t^3 + \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}t^4 + \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}t^5 + o(t^5)$$
so

- The curve passes threw the point $(0,0)$
- It is tangent to vector $(1,-2)$
- Vector $(-1,2)$ is collinear to $(1,-2)$, so nothing new
- the first non-colinear vector is $(2,0)$, so the curve presents a simple stationary point at $(0,0)$ (first direction is odd, second is even)
- don't know what to extract from the $t^5$ vector...

[image]

Comment: I mean the $o(t^5)$ is just $0$ but I get your point

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, although bit of explanations of your methodology would be most welcome. Can I ask you why did you choose to the order 5 instead of 4 for the Taylor Expansion? Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to express the entire expression, but I could (and maybe should) have stopped at order 4. The idea is you express your curve in another plane basis, the one represented by the two non-collinear vectors on the picture. In this basis, the expression is much simpler.

Comment: Yes, the $o(t^5)$ term is zero!